# Extract the authorization code from the redirect URL

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, fitbit

I am building an app that involved authorization so that I can retrieve data from a fitbit user. I have successfully gone through the steps (Link:https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/developer-guide/authorization/) up until Step 4 - Exchange the Authorization Code for the Access and Refresh Tokens.

I am getting the code
https://localhost/DailyAppleFit/?code={CODE_IM_RETRIEVING}#*=*

But do not know how to display the users Id or just something that indicates the software now has access and the user is logged in.

I have checked on postman and all of the information being passed through is correct.

After I tried the authorization code from the url, how do I use it to make a post request with headers? Once I go through that step, it returns a json file I can use to retrieve the access token.

I want to stay in the php file.

```
<?php
session_start();

function http($url, $params=false) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if($params)
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    return json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
  }

$client_id = 'CLIENT_ID_VALUE';
$client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE';
$redirect_uri = 'https://localhost/DailyAppleFit/';
$metadata_url = 'https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize';
$metadata_UrlRefreshToken = 'https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token';
$metadata = http($metadata_url);
$auth = base64_encode("{$client_id}:{$client_secret}");

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  echo '<p>Logged in as</p>';
  echo '<p>' . $_SESSION['user_id'] . '</p>';
  echo '<p><a href="/?logout">Log Out</a></p>';
  die();
}





if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    header('Location: /');
    die();
  }

if(!isset($_GET['user_id'])) {

  $_SESSION['code_verifier'] = '01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789';
  $code_challenge = base64_urlencode(hash('sha256', $_SESSION['code_verifier'], true));

  $authorize_url = 'https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?'
  .http_build_query([
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'code_challenge' => $code_challenge,
    'code_challenge_method' => 'S256',
    'scope' => 'activity heartrate location nutrition oxygen_saturation profile respiratory_rate settings sleep social temperature weight',
  ], null, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);


  echo '<p>Not logged in</p>';
  echo '<p><a href="'.$authorize_url.'">Log In</a></p>';

} else {

    if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
        die('Authorization server returned an error: '.htmlspecialchars($_GET['error']));
      }

  $response = http($redirect_uri, [
    'code' =>$_GET['code'],
    

  ]);

  $token = http($metadata, [
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
    'token'=>$response
  ]);

 
  if(!isset($response->access_token)) {
    die('Error fetching access token');
  }

  $userinfo = http($metadata->userinfo_endpoint, [
    'access_token' => $response->access_token,
  ]);

 
}

function base64_urlencode($string) {
  return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($string), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}
```

Comment: You need to make an API request to get user details next, https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/user/get-profile/